# How to reduce the number of playouts on LeelaChessZero?

Tags: engines, leela

So after checking the [wiki](https://github.com/LeelaChessZero/lc0/wiki/Lc0-options) it seems the parameter "--playouts" allows to chose the number of playouts.

But when I try it on my laptop it just fails:

```
$ ./lc0 -w meangirl-7.pb.gz --playouts 5

 v0.23.0-dev+git.f600c66 built Nov 10 2019
Unknown command line flag: --playouts.
```

So maybe it's an outdated option and/or there's a different way to change this parameter?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to add an equals sign(or something) to the parameter, so that it says

--playouts=5.

Anyway, 'Unknown command line' means that you have probably mistyped that command.

I've read the wiki as well, and it didn't specify anything.